# Is it possible to use the laptop's audio via headphone jack and Bluetooth speakers at the same time?

Tags: audio, bluetooth

Lolo Joe wants earphone jack to plug and use big speakers but at the same time he wants to partner the music coming out the earphone jack and his Bluetooth system and speakers. Is it even possible to use the earplug connection and the Bluetooth system and devices at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You can do this by **aggregating** your audio devices.

This is a function that is built into macOS; you don't need to purchase or install any additional software.

Under *MIDI Audio Setup* (under *Applications -> Utilities*), you create a new "virtual" device that aggregates audio devices:

[image]
[image]

While the pictures posted are for an input device, you can do this with output devices as well; Bluetooth, USB, and physical.

Once you create your aggregated output device of both the speakers and BT speakers, you set your application to use that device and sound will play from both devices.